# Can't implement binary search function with callback in Javascript (like a Array.find)

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback, binary-search

I try to implement function that the same is Array.find, but I would use binary search in it instead of for-cycle.

I want to pass callback to the function:

`binarySearch(elem => elem.value === 4, data)`

But i faced an issue when implemented it: I cant imagine condition I should use for decide is middle element form array less or more than value from callback

Code:

```
let data = [
    {value: 1, qwerty: "vika"},
    {value: 6, qwerty: "vika"},
    {value: -7, qwerty: "vika"},
    {value: 14, qwerty: "vika"},
    {value: 0, qwerty: "vika"},
    {value: 8, qwerty: "vika"},
    {value: 6, qwerty: "vika"},
    {value: 3, qwerty: "vika"},
    {value: -99, qwerty: "vika"},
    {value: 99, qwerty: "vika"},
    {value: 4, qwerty: "vika"},
]


data.sort((a,b) => a.value-b.value)

function binarySearch(cb, data) {
    let middle = data[Math.round(data.length/2)]
    let leftPart = data.slice(0, data.length/2)
    let rightPart = data.slice(data.length/2, data.length)
    if (cb(middle)) { return middle }
    else {
        return /*CONDITION FOR DECIDE IS MIDDLE LESS OR MORE THAN VALUE FROM CALLBACK*/
            ? binarySearch(cb, rightPart) : binarySearch(cb, leftPart)
    }
}

console.log(binarySearch(elem => elem.value === 4, data))
```

Is it even possible to implement binary search in this way?

Comment: Have your sorted the data?

Comment: Iucumt, yes, I have. But question is not that I cant _use_ it, question is i cant _implement_ it.

Comment: There is an error in your code probably start with fixing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to precise your condition. You are looking for `elem.value === 4`, but what are values "greater" than`elem.value === 4` ? Instinctively, we can say `elem.value > 4`. You should add a second callback in your parameter, for evaluating inferior / superior

```
binarySearch(equalityCallBack, greaterCallBack, data)
```

And then

```
return greaterCallBack(middle)
            ? binarySearch(equalityCallBack, greaterCallBack, rightPart) : binarySearch(equalityCallBack, greaterCallBack, leftPart)
```

#### Alternative

Or you can have one callBack, that returns 1 for "this value is too high", 0 for "this is the correct value" and -1 for "this value is too low"

```
function binarySearch(cb, data) {
    let middle = data[Math.round(data.length/2)]
    let leftPart = data.slice(0, data.length/2)
    let rightPart = data.slice(data.length/2, data.length)
    if (cb(middle) == 0) { return middle }
    else {
        return (cb(middle) == 1)
            ? binarySearch(cb, rightPart) : binarySearch(cb, leftPart)
    }
}

function cpr(a, b){
    if(a > b) return 1;
    if(a < b) return -1;
    return 0
}

console.log(binarySearch(elem => cpr(elem, 4), data))
```

Comment: Thank you, Portevent! I solved this issue as your second way, but first way via additional callback is more nice :)

Comment: you're calling the callback twice, which is not a good idea. Plus, it would be better to check for `> 0` rather than `==1` (think of callback like `obj.prop - targetValue`)

Comment: Indeed, `> 0` is more robust than `==1`. And of course you can store the callback result in a variable to save computation.